# How do I print a list of elements in array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, conditional-statements

I'm very new to JavaScript and am trying to solve this challenge.  I want to print out "A" on the first line, then "AB" on the second, then "ABC" on the third, until I print out "A....Z".  Also, when I get to E, I want to replace it with  3.  So far, I have created an array containing all the letters.  I started with a for loop, but haven't gotten far.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Post code that you tried but didn't work as expected.

Comment: pls go through the tutorials and learn

Comment: Ok, you should really do something to show us what you mean... We cannot help with these informations. Do an example on http://jsfiddle.net or just post some more code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are:

```js
var array = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var str = '';
  for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    if (array[j] == 'E') str += '3';
    else str += array[j];
  }
  document.querySelector('span').innerHTML = document.querySelector('span').innerHTML + str + '<br />';
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just added more understandable code for beginner. By the way, where is your Z in your display?

Comment: ok. if Pia is really beginner you should simplify your code like I did... you should accept 2nd snippet edit

Comment: @Julo0sS: This code is of the first days I learn programming C.

Comment: var someArray = ['a','b','c'] is far more readable for beginner... ;)

Comment: @Julo0sS: But it's a burden of `,'','',''`, too. :D

Comment: I agree... but...  :P Then, the guy has certainly more than just a span on his page... querySelector is not the best solution to me but working here. Anyway looks like his question is now solved ;)

Comment: @Julo0sS: at first, I intend to use `console.log`, but the asker is newbie... Any way, thank you.

Comment: thank you so much.  i am able to follow everything up until this part: document.querySelector('span').innerHTML = document.querySelector('span').innerHTML + str + '<br />';   can I just use console.log?

Comment: @Pia Soy: yes, go ahead certainly.

Answer (score 0):

Go simple in the first draft. Save all the alphabets in an array. Use for loop to print. And print "3" for every fifth looping.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is named  ar then i think you can do this

```
  for(var i = 0;i<ar.length;i++){
        for(var j = 0;j<=i;j++){
            if(ar[j]==='E')
                ar[j]='3';
            console.info("---->>"+ar[j]);
        }
        console.log("");
    }
```